# dplyr::group_by %>% summarise(mean) returns identical mean values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to show the means of a group that had values of over 10000 in 2015 and of a group that did not.

I could achieve it with ddply using following codes:

```
ddply(df, .(over10000 = c(df$"2015" > 10000)),function(x){data.frame("2015mean"=mean(x$"2015"))})
```

(This is how my dataframe looks. over10000 column shows if df$"2015" > 10000.)

```
head(df)
```

> ```
>    2013  2014  2015 over10000   
> 1   634   630   620     FALSE   
> 2  4330  4410  4520     FALSE   
> 3  4600  4680  4760     FALSE   
> 4 39100 40800 41800      TRUE   
> 5  3710  3750  3730     FALSE   
> 6 11900 12400 12800      TRUE
> ```

So i wanted to get the same result with dplyr using group_by & summarise.
However, somehow I am getting the mean for the whole 2015 column instead of the groups.
This is the code I used:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(over10000) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("2015mean" = mean(df$"2015", na.rm=TRUE))
```

Does anyone know why I'm having this problem?

Comment: Try: `df %>% dplyr::group_by(over10000) %>% dplyr::summarize("2015mean" = mean(\`2015\`, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `df$` in your `summarize` call. `dplyr` functions let you use bare column names within the same data frame—that's the beauty of a `dplyr` workflow. As it is, you're taking the mean of the entire vector `df$2015`, not just the part that is subset for each group

Comment: @camille's point is a little understated: you are getting wrong answers *because* you are forcing it to take the mean of the entire frame's column instead of the group's data. Use avid_useR's suggested code. Bottom line: within a pipeline, the only time you should ever use `$` or other column-extracting methods is when you are referencing data completely external to the dataset. (This is not 100% true: it might be meaningful to do `summarize('2015mean" = mean(`2015`)/mean(df$`2015`))` ... statistical meaning aside, does that help you understand when to-use/not-to-use `$`?)

Comment: @avid_useR @camille @r2evans Oh thanks everyone it works this way. I started without `df$` but didn't work because of some other mistake and while trying to fix it I ended up adding another mistake. Thank you so much for helping out such newb mistake!! :)